# ERC721 smart contract not setting metadata

Tags: solidity

I have a very simple smart contract that mints NFTs on contract creation but the issue is it is not setting NFTs metadata. I have uploaded the metadata on ipfs. When I check  metadata buy putting it in the brave browser it correctly shows up
**ipfs**: `ipfs://QmdbnwfBNE6ZekuppZnx9rk76sAmMDucnHP78UZzhwu4S3/metadata/6.json`

```
{
  "image":"ipfs://QmU9L6jiskJL7bcuu7foAgb4VThoptzZ2ByTD7AGCBwcsr/images/6.png",
  "name":"Abstract art NFT #6",
  "description":"Abstract Art"
}
```

I deployed this smart contract on rinkeby test net

**Smart contract**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Art is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable {
   using Counters for Counters.Counter;
   Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   constructor() ERC721("Art", "JL") {
       mintNFT(msg.sender,13);
   }

   function mintNFT(address recipient,uint256 _mintAmount)
       public onlyOwner
    //    returns (uint256)
   {    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= _mintAmount; i++) {
       _tokenIds.increment();

       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, "ipfs://QmdbnwfBNE6ZekuppZnx9rk76sAmMDucnHP78UZzhwu4S3/metadata/{i}.json");
    }

   }
}
```

**Contract Address**
`0x14030c04aeA36F5c57610bF912b1f435aD232f2c`

You can check the minted NFTs here: https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/art-wtudkep4ve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your tokens have the same URI of `"ipfs://QmdbnwfBNE6ZekuppZnx9rk76sAmMDucnHP78UZzhwu4S3/metadata/{i}.json"`

Solidity does not replace your `{i}` placeholder with the value of `i`. You need to do it manually with string concatenation. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do it in Solidity yet, so you'll need to use `bytes.concat` and casting `uint` to `string` (I recommend using `import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";` for this):

```
_setTokenURI(newItemId, string(bytes.concat(bytes("ipfs://QmdbnwfBNE6ZekuppZnx9rk76sAmMDucnHP78UZzhwu4S3/metadata/"), bytes(Strings.toString(i)), bytes(".json"))));
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm